# how to declare an arraylist collection class object

Tags: java

hi guys I have created a basket field in this browser class but, however I now need to declare this basket field in the browser class as  arraylist collection class object but cant figure out how to do this, below is my code so far

```
 /**
 * Write a description of class Browser here.
 * 
* @author (johnson) 
 * @version (10/12/13)
 */
public class Browser
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int iD;
    private String email;
    private int yearOfBirth;
    private boolean memberID;
    private WineCase wineCase;
    private boolean loggedIn;
    private Website website;
    private boolean discount;
    List<Boolean> basketList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

 /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Browser
     */
    public Browser()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = 00065;
        yearOfBirth = 1992;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

 /**
  * Constructor for objects of class Browser
  */
 public Browser(String newEmail,int newYearOfBirth)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = 0;
        email = newEmail;
        yearOfBirth = newYearOfBirth;
        loggedIn = false;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

 /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Browser
     */
    public Browser(int newID, String newEmail,int newYearOfBirth)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = newID;
        email = newEmail;
        yearOfBirth = newYearOfBirth;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

     /**
     * returns the ID
     */

    public int getId()
    {
    return iD;
    }


    /**
     * gets the email of the browser class
     */

    public String getEmail()
    {
    return email;
    }

    public boolean getDiscount()
    {
        return discount;
    }


    /**
     * gets the yearOfBirth for the browser class
     */

    public int yearOfBirth()
    {
    return yearOfBirth;
    }

    public double getWineCost()
    {
        return wineCase.getWineCost();
    }

     /**
     * returns 
     */

    public void setLoginStatus(boolean status)
    {
       loggedIn = status;
    }

    /**
     * returns 
     */

    public void selectWineCase(WineCase winecase)
    {
    wineCase = winecase;
    System.out.println ("Browser "+getId()+" has selcted wine case"+wineCase.getRefNo()+ "of "+winecase.getNoOfBottles()+ wineCase.getDescription()+ " at £"+wineCase.getWineCost()); 
    }

     /**
     * returns
     */

    public void payForWine()
    {
      website.checkout(this);  
    }

    public void setId()
    {
        iD = 999;
    }

     public void setWebSite(Website website)
    {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public void setDiscount(boolean discount)
    {
        this.discount = discount;
    }
}
```

any answers or replies would be greatly appreciated

Comment: One other recommendation is I would not capitalize member variables. Change Basket to lowercase to match the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

List<Boolean> basketList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

Comment: If i read your comment exactly as the error thrown, list must be in CaptialCase, like "List". Secondly, you have to use JDK 1.5 to support Generics.

Answer (score 0):

That must not be boolean as boolean is a primitive type not a collection of Objects.

 what you need to do is:

ArrayList basket = new ArrayList();

Or if you need a collection of `Boolean Objects` (still not boolean) you can do:

ArrayList basket = new ArrayList();

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're doing but declare this at the top of your class.  Also, don't forget to import packages `java.util.ArrayList` and `import java.util.List`.

```
private List<Boolean> baskets = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

This will replace the previous declaration of:

```
private boolean Basket;
```

Comment: hi i have declared the above code but i now get an error cannot find symbol- class list

Comment: Did you add imports?  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

Answer (score 0):

A list of Boolean(s)?

```
java.util.List<Boolean> basketAl = new java.util.ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

And I urge you to add a toString method to your class

```
// Something like this...
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(iD).append(" ").append(email).append(" ");
  sb.append(yearOfBirth).append(" ").append(memberID).append(" ");
  sb.append(wineCase).append(" ").append(loggedIn).append(" ");
  sb.append(website).append(" ").append(discount).append(" ");
  sb.append(Basket);
  return sb.toString();
}
```